# SpringMVC cannot return Json or Xml,Http 406

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have jar files imported and `@ResponseBody` added,nothing happens
I also used

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

nothing happens.
I have suffered this all day

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd"
       default-autowire="byName">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                    <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                        <list>
                            <value>text/plain;charset=UTF-8</value>
                            <value>text/json;charset=UTF-8</value>
                            <value>text/xml;charset=UTF-8</value>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources location="/static/" mapping="/static/**"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.format.demo.controller" />

    <import resource="classpath:springConfig/viewConfig/freemarker.xml"/>


</beans>
```

applicationContext.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd" default-autowire="byName">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.format.demo">
        <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression="org.format.demo.controller.*"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/springmvc?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8"></property>
        <property name="user" value="root"></property>
        <property name="password" value="123456"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.format.demo.model" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                    org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">
                    true
                </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

    <aop:config>
        <aop:advisor pointcut="execution(* org.format.demo.service.impl.*Service.*(..))" advice-ref="txAdvice"/>
    </aop:config>
    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/>
            <tx:method name="query*" read-only="true"/>
            <tx:method name="find*" read-only="true"/>
            <tx:method name="load*" read-only="true"/>
            <tx:method name="*" rollback-for="Exception" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>


</beans>
```

web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--suppress ALL -->
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:springConfig/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        <!--<param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>-->
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>Set Character Encoding</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Set Character Encoding</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:springConfig/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>


</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.format.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>springmvc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <!--  spring dependency start  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--  spring dependency end  -->


        <!--  hibernate dependency  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--  hibernate dependency  -->



        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.20</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--        servlet         -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.30</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Json-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>1</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <stopPort>9966</stopPort>
                    <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                    <connectors>
                        <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                            <port>8888</port>
                            <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
                        </connector>
                    </connectors>
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <contextPath>/SpringMVCDemo</contextPath>
                    </webAppConfig>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>generator</finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

I use controller like this

```
package org.format.demo.controller;

import org.format.demo.model.Employee;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import java.util.Date;

/**
 * @Auther: Good
 * @Date: 2019/1/11 09:02
 * @Description:
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public class TestController {


    @RequestMapping(value="/testCustomObj", produces={"application/json; charset=UTF-8"})
    @ResponseBody
    public Employee testCustomObj(Employee e) {
        return e;
    }
}
```

I input http://localhost:8080/springmvcdemo/test/testCustomObj?id=1&name=ss on Url,then i get

```
HTTP Status 406 -

type Status report

message

description The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.59
```

I find that browser return text/html, it seems like application/json has no Effect

How can i fix this issue, please help me, thanks.
I uploaded this demo to the github,https://github.com/cjy513203427/springmvcdemo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwDmM.png)

Comment: Remove Employee e from method and create some response and bind it in json or some browser understandable format. As you're returning e which browser will not understand.

Comment: public Employee testCustomObj() {
        Employee e = new Employee();
        e.setId(1);
        e.setName("sss");
        e.setAge(22);
        return e;
    }

Comment: Thankx,i remove Employee e,still not works,the same issue

Comment: Works like it should. Your browser requests `text/html` but your controller can only send JSON. Hence it won't match/work. Code and Spring work as they should.

Comment: Now i know the cause,gratitude,i am still working on it

Comment: @Jonas If you discovered the cause please post it here for other users which have the same problem. Thanks

Comment: You have limited the response to only produce JSON. You are sending a request that only supports HTML, XHTML or XML... Hence it won't match, hence the 406. Use something like POSTMAN and make sure that `application/json` is part of the accept header in your request.

Comment: Please share your web.xml as well

Comment: I shared my web.xml file

Comment: I use Postman,it said Content-Type →text/html;charset=utf-8

Comment: I still get the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the Reason why i get 406,i annotate bean RequestMappingHandlerAdapter configuration,i find it works,then i debug RequestHandlerMapping.java,in method afterPropertiesSet(),i debug this.returnValueHandlers,i find that there is 7 messageConverters,i have not MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter and Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter

I lacked

```
<bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter"/>
```

I added two beans into dispatcher-servlet.xml,then it works.

MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter can parse Json.
Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter can parse Xml.

the final dispatcher-servlet.xml is like this

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd"
       default-autowire="byName">

    <!-- 防止@ResponseBody出现的中文乱码 -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                    <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                        <list>
                            <value>text/plain;charset=UTF-8</value>
                            <value>text/json;charset=UTF-8</value>
                            <value>text/xml;charset=UTF-8</value>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

   

    <!-- 防止@ResponseBody出现的中文乱码 -->
    <!-- 启动Spring MVC的注解功能，完成请求和注解POJO的映射 -->
    <mvc:resources location="/static/" mapping="/static/**"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.format.demo.controller" />


    <!--
    <import resource="classpath:springConfig/viewConfig/jsp.xml"/>
    -->
    <import resource="classpath:springConfig/viewConfig/freemarker.xml"/>


</beans>
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the answer. I think Spring Boot might be doing this automatically, because I haven't encountered this issue, but I moved to Spring Boot over the past few years.

Comment: Thanks for watching.Yes,SpringBoot is clever.SpringMVC also configured this automatically,but configuration that i specified is missing,i added two Beans,then it works. I am recently using SpringBoot,but i want to read the source of Spring,so i start from a simple demo of SpringMVC

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this as follows

```
   @RequestMapping(value="/testCustomObj", 
                   produces={"application/json; charset=UTF-8"}, 
                   method = RequestMethod.GET)
   @ResponseBody
   public Employee testCustomObj(@RequestParam(value = "id") int id, 
                                 @RequestParam(value = "name") String name)
```

I happen to have [JSONView](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc?hl=en) extension installed in Chrome, so maybe it is adding `"application/json"` to the accept headers, but I doubt it.

You might also want to use something like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to have full control on the headers you are sending to your REST API.

Comment: I can receive parameter id and name,but still get HTTP 406

Comment: Can you try to temporarily change your `@RequestMapping` to `produces={"text/html"}`? What browser are you using?

Comment: Thanks for watching,I use Firefox,when i change produces as you said,still get Http 406,i added a screenshot to the question

Comment: I still get the same issue

Comment: Some people seem to have solved the issue by adding the `jackson-mapper-asl` dependency. Try that. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.13

Comment: Jar has not Problem,i lacked two Beans